# Postive Integers and Unsigned in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have read that SQL Server has the ability to create an unsigned integer column and I also read that SQL Server does not allow creation of integer unsigned column. So I'm confused as to which is actually correct.

I need to create a new column in my table called QuantityonHand. This column should be an integer of 5 characters and only accept positive numbers.

So do I create the column as;

```
(1) QuantityonHand [unsigned] int (5) which means the number can only be positive OR

(2) QuantityonHand int (5) default 0 - which means the number cannot be less than zero, the default 0 being the condition in the column.
```

I am leaning towards the second one, but I was hoping to get some guidance before I add the column and mess up my table.

Thanks everyone
Josie

Answer (score 4):

There are no unsigned data types, but you can use a check constraint to allow only certain range of values. You can find information for example from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is no `UNSIGNED` version of `INT` see: **[`UNSIGNED INTEGER Data Type`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/515502/unsigned-integer-data-type)**

> I need to create a new column in my table called QuantityonHand. This
>   column should be an integer of 5 characters and only accept positive
>   numbers.

Use standard `INT` and add `CHECK` constraint.

```
QuantityonHand INT CHECK (QuantityonHand >= 0 AND QuantityonHand <= 99999)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/380363)**</kbd>

Comment: @Josie By `This column should be an integer of 5 characters and only accept positive numbers.` you mean up to 99999 or 5 character integer?

Comment: @lad2025.....Thank ye both, that is what I did added the column as int with a check constraint to be greater than zero.

Comment: @JamesZ.....Thank you, that is what I did, added an int column with a check constraint > 0